# Building a site with complicated internalization support

Tags: mysql, database-design, internationalization

When a user browses some page and then switches a language, then the following actions should occur:

- If there's a translation for a page he's browsing now, then do redirect to that page.
- If there's no translated version of that page, then do redirect to a home page.

So for example, a user browses `/about-us` page then he switched to German language, then he should be redirected to `/uber-uns` if a translation of `/about-us` in german exists.

Currently I have a structure like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
  `language` varchar(3),
  `urlSegment` varchar(250), 
  `content` TEXT

) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

What relationships/columns should be added to achieve that?

Comment: that approach is very complicated to implement ( about-us -> über uns - i hate redirects ;-) ), rather add the countrycode as part of the URL on every page: mypage.com/de-DE/uniquename.html ) and let the server handle the rest ( fetch translation, if not fallback to english ). If you require permanent-links, store the language chosen into a cookie ( no cookie -> en ) and remove that language code from the url I suggested

Comment: Like @nazjero says, you need a language identifier in your URL structure and you are set. No reason to make this more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: I don't think redirect the homepage when the translation is not there is a good idea. Ideally, you should have a database table to localize language strings. <navigation/home/, en_US, home>, <navigation/home/, zh-CN, 主页>

Comment: It's much better to switch on the user's Accept-Language header, than redirecting to a completely different URI. You can always provide the URI as well (and an unobtrusive link) for users that don't have their browser correctly configured.

Comment: (Most users' browsers will be configured with correct Accept-Language headers, because this is defaulted on browser installation according to their operating system locale.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One page can have multiple translations, so you need one-to-many relationship schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pages (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE page_translations (

  page_id INT NOT NULL
  language varchar(3),
  url_segment varchar(250) UNIQUE,
  content TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (page_id) REFERENCES pages(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(page_id,language)

) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

In the `pages` table you can store some useful data related to all translations of the page.

Then, knowing `url_segment` of the current page, you can easily get the `url_segment` of this page in another language:

```sql
SELECT new.url_segment
FROM page_translations AS new,
     page_translations AS cur
WHERE new.page_id = cur.page_id
  AND cur.url_segment = '/about-us'
  AND new.language = 'de'
```

Comment: Well, you're saying its better to store things like *page name, title, meta keywords, meta description*... in the pages table, right?

Comment: If these fields are never translated, then yes. Overwise it is more reasonable to store localized data in the `page_translations` table.

Comment: I'd still put the language in the URL ,so you won't have collisions in the url_segment namespace. Depending on the subject of your domain [loanwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) may be commonplace.

Comment: You could make (language, url_segment) unique and serve according to requested languagecode in Accept-Language header or URL.